# example of parsing a receipt for an in-app purchase using iOS Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin.ios, in-app-purchase, restsharp

I am trying to implement purchase validation for my app.  I see that I can send the purchase receipt to my server to verify with Apple.  However, I cannot figure out the correct way to POST the NSData to my URL for validation.  Something like this:

```
public void CompleteTransaction (SKPaymentTransaction transaction) {
    var productId = transaction.Payment.ProductIdentifier;
    NSUrl receiptURL = NSBundle.MainBundle.AppStoreReceiptUrl;
    NSData theData = NSData.FromUrl (receiptURL);

    RestRequest request = new RestRequest(validationURL, Method.POST);
    request.AddBody(theData); // ??  
    restClient.ExecuteAsync<bool>((response) =>
        {
            FinishTransaction(transaction, response.Data);
        });
}
```

Does anyone have an example?  I am using RestSharp.

Thanks!

- davevr

Answer (score 3):

OK, found how to do it.  The trick was to parse the receipt into a dictionary and then pull the key out of that.  Sample code:

```
public void CompleteTransaction (SKPaymentTransaction transaction) {
    var productId = transaction.Payment.ProductIdentifier;
    NSUrl receiptURL = NSBundle.MainBundle.AppStoreReceiptUrl;
    NSData receipt = NSData.FromUrl (receiptURL);

    // here is the code I was missing
    NSDictionary requestContents = NSDictionary.FromObjectAndKey((NSString)receipt.GetBase64EncodedString(
                NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.None), 
                (NSString)"receipt-data");

    string receiptData = (requestContents["receipt-data"] as NSString).ToString();

    RestRequest request = new RestRequest(<url to your server>, Method.POST);

    request.AddParameter ("receipt-data", receiptData );

    apiClient.ExecuteAsync<bool>(request, (response) => 
        {
            FinishTransaction (transaction, response.Data);
        });
```

Once that is done, you can do the validation on the Apple server.  There is lots of sample code on the net for that part.

Comment: Hi Dave,
I was able to generate the receipt-data from my iOS xamarin project. But when I try to validate on Apple it gives me 2100 status.

That means the token is not valid.

Can u tell me what's wrong here?

Comment: You mean, on your server side?